# Bug with Drag and Drop API implementation

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

During these days I was trying to learn how to implement Drag and Drop API but I ran into a bug I can't fix. Practically, if I swap first and second box by drag, when I select the header and drag it into the second box, there happens the bug! This is just a case but there are even more. I'm trying to see what happen with the debug but I miss something. Below a screenshot of the bug and code:

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCGeu.png)

```js
let dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.classList.add('dnd__element--dragStart');

  console.log(this);
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add('dnd__element--dragOver');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dnd__element--dragOver');
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dnd__element--dragStart');

  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('dnd__element--dragOver');
  });
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
  }

  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  }

  return false;
}

const items = document.querySelectorAll('.dnd__element');
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.classList.remove(
    'dnd__element--dragStart',
    'dnd__element--dragEnd',
    'dnd__element--dragOver'
  );
  item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

```css
.dnd__element {
  cursor: move;
  border: 3px solid #777;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  float: left;
}

.dnd__element--dragStart {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.dnd__element--dragEnd {
  opacity: 1;
}

.dnd__element--dragOver {
  border: 3px dotted #666;
}

.dnd__drag-zone {
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

.heading-tertiary {
  display: block;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section-dnd">
    <div class="dnd__drag-zone">
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Drag zone</h3>
      <div class="dnd__element dnd__element--dragStart" id="d1" draggable="true">
        Box 1
      </div>
      <div class="dnd__element dnd__element--dragEnd" id="d2" draggable="true">
        Box 2
      </div>
      <div class="dnd__element dnd__element--dragOver" draggable="true">
        Box 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful when you describe the bug. I don't know what the image should show us. Your code works – the 3 boxes are exchangeble via drag & drop...

Comment: Hey there! I wrote it into the question:  "Practically, if I swap first and second box by drag, when I select the header and drag it into the second box, there happens the bug!". That's the procedure to create the bug.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the fast reply. Now i got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to rely on '*handleDragStart()*' because it can only be called with 1 of the 3 valid items. So set a test variable in that handler (for example `started = true;`) and check for it (`if (started)`) in '*handleDragEnter()*' and '*handleDrop()*'.

(reset '*started*' to false in '*handleDrop()*')...

**Working example**:

```js
var started = false;
let dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.classList.add('dnd__element--dragStart');

  started = true;
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  if (started) this.classList.add('dnd__element--dragOver');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dnd__element--dragOver');
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dnd__element--dragStart');

  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('dnd__element--dragOver');
  });

  started = false;
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
  }

  if (started && dragSrcEl != this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  }

  started = false;
  return false;
}

const items = document.querySelectorAll('.dnd__element');
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.classList.remove(
    'dnd__element--dragStart',
    'dnd__element--dragEnd',
    'dnd__element--dragOver'
  );
  item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

```css
.dnd__element {
  cursor: move;
  border: 3px solid #777;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  float: left;
}

.dnd__element--dragStart {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.dnd__element--dragEnd {
  opacity: 1;
}

.dnd__element--dragOver {
  border: 3px dotted #666;
}

.dnd__drag-zone {
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

.heading-tertiary {
  display: block;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-dnd">
    <div class="dnd__drag-zone">
        <h3 class="heading-tertiary">Drag zone</h3>
        <div class="dnd__element dnd__element--dragStart" id="d1" draggable="true">
            Box 1
        </div>
        <div class="dnd__element dnd__element--dragEnd" id="d2" draggable="true">
            Box 2
        </div>
        <div class="dnd__element dnd__element--dragOver" draggable="true">
            Box 3
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I still get some bugs. For example do ctrl+a on the snippet and drag box 2 to dragzone header and then the latter to box 1. This code is getting me crazy!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to reset 'started' to false also in 'handleDragEnd()' – fixed it now in the answer...

Comment: Did you test it after my fix? Are there other errors - and if yes which errors?

Comment: No sorry, I didn't refresh the page. Now is perfect and the solution is simple and clear, thank you very much!